# Lightroom's graduated filter lines not showing

Tags: lightroom, graduated-filters

Since the update to Lightroom Classic CC, the graduated filter (and the radial filter), with "Show edit pins" set to "Auto" doesn't show the guides on their first use on a picture. I have to get the cursor out of the image, then back again, to make them appear.

There's no problem if the "Show edit pins" option is set to "Always".

Anyone with the same issue? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a similar issue to this not so long ago, the simple fix was simply to press the h key as a shortcut, this resolved it for me.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Matthew Pressing "h" solved the issue for me